# How to use Apache Flink CEP SQL for getting events from already matched pattern?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, flink-sql, flink-batch

My requirement is to generate trigger based on 2 events(EVT_A & EVT_B independent of order). Here is expectation

```
1. EVT_A arrived. --> No action
2. EVT_B arrived  --> Should Trigger
3. EVT_B arrived  --> should Trigger since A was received previously (o/p should include A and current B)
4. EVT_A arrived  --> should Trigger since B was received previously (o/p should include current A and last B)
5. EVT_A arrived  --> should Trigger since B was received previously (o/p should include current A and last B)
```

I tried following but no success.

```
SELECT E.*
From MyEvents
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
    ORDER BY procTime
    MEASURES ARRAY[
        Event(A.id, A.name, A.date),
        Event(B.id, B.name, B.date)
    ] AS Events
    AFTER MATCH SKIP TO NEXT ROW
    PATTERN (A C* B)
    DEFINE
        A AS name in ('EVT_A', 'EVT_B'),
        B AS name in ('EVT_A', 'EVT_B') AND B.name <> A.name,
        C AS name not in ('EVT_A', 'EVT_B')
) AS E;
```

I also tried with "*AFTER MATCH SKIP TO FIRST A*". But it also therw exception. Any suggestions how can I achieve this with Flink SQL CEP or any other way in Flink.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a case where a RichFlatMap or a ProcessFunction is the easiest way to go. Just need a bit of state:

```java
ValueState<Event> lastA;
ValueState<Event> lastB;
```

And then the logic for processing each incoming event is something like this:

```
if EVT_A
  store event as lastA
  emit lastB with this event unless lastB is null
if EVT_B
  store event as lastB
  emit lastA with this event unless lastA is null
```

If you are looking for an introduction to working with Flink's managed state, there's a [tutorial in the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/etl.html).

Comment: Thanks David For your response. In my actual business usecase, I am going to receive SQL(rather triggering condition) dynamically from other service. hence I was looking at options available with CEP SQL or normal SQL. Plus I may receive triggering condition on 2 to 15 events as well. Is there any way to handle this dynamically?